# calculating sum of specific rows in excel sheet using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

hi:) i'm a newbie at python and would like to ask for help to calculaate the sum of specific rows in an excel worksheet. i've tried searching for help online however, all examples given were different to my situation, so i found it difficult to modify the code to my needs. this is the code i've used.
(need to calculate sum of the values inside rows for specific country within sheet)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\julia\OneDrive\Documents\python assignment\2016 data -EU 
values.xlsx', sheet_name='PM10 ')
for row in plot.iterrows():
    if 'Country' == 'Malta':
      sum_pollution = plot['AirPollutionLevel'].sum()
    print()
```

for context, the excel sheet looks something like this [image: link to pic]:

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
df[df["country"] == "Malta"]["AirPollutionLevel"].sum()
```

Steps in the code above:

- Grab all the rows where country equals Malta
- Grab the AirPollutionLevel column of this subset
- Sum it!

Comment: thanks for the input @Christian! i tried that but it's telling me it cant find 'Country' even though it's in the excel sheet..im quite confused. i'll attach a link to a screenshot of my excel sheet in case u can help me further

Comment: You should skip some rows when reading that excel sheet, Pandas is not detecting "Country" as a header. Try this: `pd.read_excel("...", sheet_name='PM10 ', skiprows=6)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `iterrows()` you can do:

EDIT: `skiprows` added, since your real data starts at row 7

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\julia\OneDrive\Documents\python assignment\2016 data -EU 
values.xlsx', sheet_name='PM10 ', skiprows=6)

result = 0

for row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1]['Country'] == 'Malta':
        result += row[1]['AirPollutionLevel']

print(result)
```

Comment: thanks! unfortunately, it is giving me the same error as the other answer, which is: KeyError: 'Country'. not sure how to get around this as the word country is in the excel sheet..

Comment: I've solved it now, but thank you @Jonas for your help!